# Registration of a new FaceID user on iphone from within an app, using Swift code

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui, face-id

iPhone has a FaceID user registration or enrollment process through an option found in the settings section.
Is it possible to trigger this process from within an app, using Swift code?

Comment: No, not possible. See [`LAContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext) for what you can do (not my downvotes).

Comment: How this could be safe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not simple possible to launch a FaceID registration process from an app, because this would be unsafe. But you can open the settings app and even the settings of your app via an URL. There you can see if the app is able to use FaceID. This is the closest you can get to the `FaceID & Code` Settings. Probably give the user some instruction where to find it.

```
                guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
                    return
                }
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                                print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
                            })
                        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify how opening the Settings page for your own app allows your app to launch the interface for setting up FaceID?

Comment: @HangarRash As you said before, it is not possible to open a FaceID user registration process to setup a new face, but giving the user an instruction beforehand and opening the settings it is the closest thing you can get. Also if your app supports FaceID the FaceID Boolean shows up if the app is allowed to use FaceID or not.

Comment: You should update your answer with those details. As written, your answer is written as if simply launching the app settings is how an app can start the FaceID registration process.

Comment: Excellent. I sensed from the beginning that it was not possible and I agree with the idea that it would not be safe. It is very interesting the option to trigger access to settings from the application, but being a digital wallet application, linked to a session, a token, etc., etc., it does not seem to me a good idea to send the user to the settings. Perhaps the best thing to do would be to indicate by means of a message that the biometric login will not be available until the user registers using the mechanism provided by the platform.
Thank you very much for your invaluable input.